# wkhtmltopdf on a Mac - how does it get executed?

Tags: macos, wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to get wktmtlmtopdf running on a MacBook Pro with OSX Yosemite.

I ran the package installer for wkhtmltopdf 0.12.2.1 and it placed it in `user/local/bin`

But, when I run the following, I get a different version.

```
$ wkhtmltopdf -V
Name:
  wkhtmltopdf 0.9.9

$ which wkhtmltopdf
/Users/davidburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/wkhtmltopdf
```

Why isn't it running the 0.12.2.1 version?

Why does `$ which wkhtmltopdf` point to the one in gems?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `which wkhtmltopdf` -- you probably have the older version installed in `/usr/bin` which you'll have to remove manually.

Answer (score 1):

For macOS Mojave, try out:

```
sudo uninstall-wkhtmltox
```